# Как, при определенных условиях, не вставлять значение при объявлении массива php?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

```
$bool = false;    
$attributes = [
    'id',
    'name',
    $bool ? 'surname' : null,
];
```

Можно ли просто пропускать вставку значения в массив, когда $bool == false?
Интересует пропуск вставки именно в таком виде, а не в таком:

```
$bool = false;    
$attributes = [
    'id',
    'name',
];

if ($bool)
    $attributes[] = 'surname'
```

Comment: Очевидно, что __нельзя__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что нельзя. – u_mulder